# force user to select only results from collection in auto complete textbox

Tags: c#, autocomplete

in C# WinForms app I have a collection of strings, and want to force the user to ONLY be able to select from the options that I provide, so they CANT actually type free text in a textbox control I am using SuggestAppend but when the current user types I need to limit the results.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you set the `AutoComplete` mode to `ListItems`?

Comment: You can check on each character entered if the users partial word is contained within yours. Of course, it depends on how big your list is as to if this is too resource intensive or not. If it doesn't appear, then you can add a warning message or similar. Is there a reason you want this with a TextBox control instead of a  combobox or similar?

Comment: ListItems mode? where can I set this?

Comment: Read my answer and comment there. Are you using a `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case would be a ComboBox better. There you can set the Items, and the user is not allowed to type anything.

Answer (score 0):

Always use a `ComboBox`

If you don't want to let them type you want to set the `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList`

If you want to let them type in stuff you set the `AutoCompleteMode` to `SuggestAppend` and the `AutoCompleteSource` to `ListItems`.

A `TextBox` has the same properties. So you can set `AutoCompleteMode` to `SuggestAppend` and in your code behind do this for example:
`textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = yourStringArray;`

Comment: You can do exactly the same with a TextBox. I wouldn't see why however but I'll edit my answer to show you.

Comment: Thanks Toon. I have that already done. But a can type any text still, I need to restrict them to ONLY items in the list

Comment: I know of no decent way to do this. I check if what they typed is in the collection on submitting. @Dave Rook's comment to your question could help you but it's not something I'd do if not absolutely neccessary.